# the equation $y^2=4x+4y$ changes to the form $y^2=4x$ if the origin shifted to (without rotating the axis)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, conic-sections

the equation $y^2=4x+4y$ changes to the form $y^2=4x$ if the origin shifted to (without rotating the axis)

$A:(1,2)$

$B:(-1,2)$

$C:(-1,-2)$

$D:(1,-2)$

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint: draw the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Being the lazy person I am, I just plugged in A, B, C, and D to get a feel for the problem. Then, we can take some values for $y^2=4x+4y$.

$x = -1, y = 2$

$x = 0, y = 4$

$x = 1, y \approx 4.82$

As you can see, when $x = -1$, $y = 2$. The answer choice is B.

-FruDe

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$y^2=4x+4y$ is equivalent to $(y-2)^2=4(x+1)$.

Comment: i have no idea what to find in this . the question itself i don;t understand

Comment: Then did you try drawing the graph, as @Ethan Bolker wisely suggested?

Comment: You blew my cover!

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the blanks to by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

$y^2=4x+4y$

$y^2-4y=4x$

$y^2-4x+\color{blue}{?}=4x+\color{blue}{?}$

$(y-\color{green}{?})^2=4(x-\color{red}{?})$

$(y')^2=4x'$ where $(x',y')=(0,0)$ when $(x,y)=(\color{red}{?},\color{green}{?})$.